# java mysql database insert using prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I've seen a lot of questions regarding this topic but none seems to be the correct solution. I've trying to insert a new row into my database using preparedstatements but I'm getting an error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, guess, answer, value) VALUES (17, 187, 224, 276, 19, ' at line 1
```

This is my code:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO block (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, guess, answer, value)" + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setInt(1, array[0]);
        pst.setInt(2, array[1]);
        pst.setInt(3, array[2]);
        pst.setInt(4, array[3]);
        pst.setInt(5, array[4]);
        pst.setInt(6, array[5]);
        pst.setInt(7, array[6]);
        pst.setInt(8, array[7]);
        pst.setInt(9, array[8]);
        pst.setString(10, String.valueOf(letter[guess]));
        pst.setString(11, String.valueOf(answer));
        pst.setInt(12, value);

        pst.executeUpdate();
```

This is my db:
[sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5IZl.png)

I feel like I'm missing something really simple. . .

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Are `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` actual columns in your `block` table?

Comment: yes, they're the actual names

Comment: is Parameter index starts from 1 ? maybe you should start with pst.setInt(0, array[0]);

Comment: @mBogaz Yes, JDBC parameter indexes start from 1 ... yes, it's a pain

Comment: `value` may be a reserved SQL word

Comment: before pst.executeUpdate(); print the query and try to run from sql manually. See what is the problem

Comment: alright, i'll try both suggestions

Comment: i tried running the query from sql, the value word is highlighted, so yeah i think it really is a keyword. . .

Comment: i tried changing it and i ran the code, it works now! you guys are awesome! thanks!

Comment: that was a false alarm, it's still not working, but i'll keep trying hahahaha

Comment: Column names that start with (or are) numbers are a bad idea as they require quoting everywhere you use them.  You could call them `c1`, `c2`, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax problem. Here's what [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) says:

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

So you probably need to quote your field names:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO block (\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\"
 , \"6\", \"7\", \"8\", \"9\", \"guess\", \"answer\", \"value\")" +
    " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

You need to be sure whether the `guess`, `answer`, and `value` fields' case-sensitivity applies.